# macOS screenshots now default to Mail.app - how do I change them back to save on Desktop?

Tags: macos, apple-mail, screenshot

I've somehow managed to change the default behaviour of macOS Sierra's Cmd+Shift+4 screenshot behaviour so that it places the screenshot inside a new mail message. I vaguely remember seeing this setting somewhere and thinking "cool! That might be useful".

But I don't want that! I just want it to save to my Desktop. I've tried the usual `defaults write com.apple.screencapture locate ~/Desktop` trick, to no avail.

My question:

1) For people who might actually want this, how did I do it?
2) I don't want it! How do I change it back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.

It's on the Touch Bar.

1. Press Cmd+Shift+4
2. Your Touch Bar displays an option, 'Save to:'
3. Change that from 'Mail' to 'Desktop' (or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I personally did this "mistake", but don't worry, there is a super software that is called [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) and with it, you can change many things such as the screenshots output directory. So, when you have installed [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html), you'll need the admin password. After you typed it, you'll have to accept terms and conditions, and then OnyX will want to check your disk's structure, you have to click on cancel (you can click on continue, but that will just take more time). Now, click on settings, and on the first page, you'll be able to change the screenshot output directory.

Comment: While this lets you change the default save location, it doesn't alter the behaviour I described which is, presumably, unique to the new MBPs with Touch Bar.